# E/Volley: [6074] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for

Tags: java, android, api, android-volley, android-glide

1. activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

2.activity_frame.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="411dp"
            android:layout_height="360dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textview1"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.173" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textview2"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

2. HDNews.java

package com.example.android.hdnews;

```
public class HDNews {

    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String image;

    public HDNews(String title, String author, String image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

3. MainActivity.java

   package com.example.android.hdnews;

   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
   import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.LinearLayout;

   import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
   import com.android.volley.Request;
   import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
   import com.android.volley.Response;
   import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
   import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
   import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

   import org.json.JSONArray;
   import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private RecyclerView recyclerView;

   private ArrayList al;

   private HDNewsAdapter hdNewsAdapter;

   private RequestQueue requestQueue;

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.rView);
       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
       al=new ArrayList<HDNews>();
       requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
       extractingDataFromInternet();
   }
   //http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=94bf8bcc374b494485309e325e3656f9
   public void extractingDataFromInternet(){
      String url="http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=business&apiKey=94bf8bcc374b494485309e325e3656f9";
       JsonObjectRequest JsonObjReq=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

           @Override
           public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
               try {
                   JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("articles");
                   for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                       JSONObject ca = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       String authorNames = ca.optString("author");
                       String titleNames = ca.optString("title");
                       String imageUrls = ca.getString("urlToImage");
                       al.add(new HDNews(titleNames, authorNames, imageUrls));
                   }
                   hdNewsAdapter = new HDNewsAdapter(MainActivity.this, al);
                   recyclerView.setAdapter(hdNewsAdapter);
               } catch ( JSONException e ) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          }
      });
         requestQueue.add(JsonObjReq);
   }
   ```

   }
4. HDNewsAdapter

   package com.example.android.hdnews;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
   import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

   import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

   import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class HDNewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HDNewsAdapter.ViewHolder>{

   ```
   private Context context;
   private ArrayList<HDNews> al;
   public HDNewsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HDNews> al) {
       this.context = context;
       this.al = al;
   }
   @NonNull
   @Override
   public HDNewsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View views= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_frame,parent,false);
       return new ViewHolder(views);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
               HDNews currentposition=al.get(position);
               String imgurl=currentposition.getImage();
               String athName=currentposition.getAuthor();
               String ttleName=currentposition.getTitle();
       holder.titleName01.setText(ttleName);
       holder.authorName01.setText(athName);
       Glide.with(context).load(imgurl).into(holder.imageurl01);
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return al.size();
   }

   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
       public TextView authorName01;
       public TextView titleName01;
       public ImageView imageurl01;
       public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           authorName01=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           titleName01=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
           imageurl01=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       }

       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: help me please in this question

Comment: 403 error means that your server forbids your request. Ensure that you are authorized and backend is ok for your request.

Comment: I can't understand please explain it

Comment: Please look at REST response codes. You need to provide your login/password or access token when you try to get this resource

Comment: please help me my account is block